# How to prevent hardcoding addresses in a web project?

Tags: web-development, design-patterns

In a fairly complicated web application, there are almost hundreds of redirecting to another page, or linking to another page, etc. Imagine that you have a page called `/services/users/register-new-user` and in many places you want to redirect users to this page, or you want to provide links to this page. However, if for any reason in future, you change this address to something like `/users/register`, you should update all links, otherwise they won't resolve. I'm finding myself always encountering this problem, since wherever I want to redirect or link to `/services/users/register-new-user` I hard-code the entire relative address.

How can I improve this pattern?

Comment: use a constant variable in a configuration class.  If you do change the name of the page, its easy to resolve, you could even generate a small utility to create the class for you.  Really the simply solution is to avoid trivial changes like changing the file name.

Comment: Why don't you use Resources?

Comment: @Ramhound, what about a website with 10,000 pages? You can't create constants for every page. But the idea of a URL generator class is not bad. But I think there should be a better way. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious thing that springs to mind is to hold the address in a variable and always use that when building the URL you need.

Then if you change the URL you just need to update the variable.

Other alternatives are to use a pattern like MVC routes to build up your addresses. Then you just need to update the logic that defines your routes.

Comment: Good suggestion @ChrisF. However, for languages that don't have route engine (like PHP, correct me if I'm wrong), writing a route engine is not very easy. Also for websites with great number of pages, storing URLs in variables doesn't sound being feasible. :)

Comment: You can write routing in PHP, and it exists in many framework. Code igniter for exemple has a good support for routes.

Comment: @Saeed - I can't think of any *language* that has a routing engine built in. A lot of *frameworks* do however.

Comment: @Saeed: Why doesn't it sound feasible to store lots of URLs in variables?